# Why does SplFileInfo return a wrong size

Tags: php, file, io

Once a file size is read, you can change the file, the returned size is always the same.

Why ? How can I have PHP to return actual data ?

My PHP version (on Windows today)

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.2.0 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2017 23:48:32) ( NTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

The test code

```
<?php
$fn = 'myfile.txt';
file_put_contents($fn, "abcd\n");           // I have some file somewhere ...
$fi = new \SplFileInfo($fn);
echo 'Size is ', $fi->getSize(), PHP_EOL;   // Ok, size is 5
file_put_contents($fn, "abcd\nefgh\n");     // Putsize=10 content
echo 'Size is ', $fi->getSize(), PHP_EOL;   // Still shows 5
unset($fi);                                 // Free info object
$fi = new \SplFileInfo($fn);                // And start over,
echo 'Size is ', $fi->getSize(), PHP_EOL;   // But still 5
$fw = $fi->openFile('w');                   // Write with objects because
$fw->fwrite("abcd\nefgh\nijkl\n");          // maybe they share fileinfo data
echo 'Size is ', $fw->getSize(), PHP_EOL;   // but still has file = 5
echo 'filesize() ', filesize($fn), PHP_EOL; // Alternative function
```

The output

```
Size is 5
Size is 5
Size is 5
Size is 5
filesize() 5
```

It may make sense to you, but to me certainly not. I'm thinking about data cached by PHP, so I try to trigger destructors with `unset()` but it has no effect.

So, how to tell PHP to give me what I want ?

Thank you

Comment: The duplicate is for linux, if this isn't a similar problem I'll remove it.

Comment: @NigelRen yea, that explains it. just tested it on Windows

Comment: Hi @NigelRen yeah it is a duplicate, sorry for that, did not show in the suggestions. Should I remove it or copy the solution ? Thanks